# Need to sub count in a count

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following, we get a count of how many times a patient did not show for an medical appointment (NOSHOW). It is based on if they did not show for the current day, then we display their count of this from the past. How can I get also  the department that they did not show for? We have 6 different medical department so the manager wants to see if the problem is only for say dental, or for all. This will assist them from perhaps not booking someone etc.

```
SELECT Distinct 
    Appt_DateTime j, 
    Patient_Name j, 
    Appt_Status j,    
    Appt_Sched_Department_ID j, 
    Appt_Sched_Department_Descr j, 
    Patient_id j,  
    Patient_number j, 
    Appt_NoShow_Date j,
    ISNULL(P.NotShowCount,0) AS NotShowCount

FROM
    vwGenPatInfo vwGenPatInfo j 
    INNER JOIN vwGenPatApptInfo vwGenPatApptInfo ON vwGenPatInfo.Patient_ID=vwGenPatApptInfo.Patient_ID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Patient_ID, COUNT(Appt_Status) AS NotShowCount 
        FROM (SELECT Appt_DateTime, Appt_Status, Appt_Sched_Department_ID, Appt_Sched_Department_Descr, Appt_NoShow_Date, Patient_ID
            FROM vwGenPatapptInfo AS vwGenPatApptInfo
            WHERE      (Appt_Status = 'N') AND (Appt_DateTime < DATEADD(day,  DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), - 1))) AS L
    GROUP BY 
        Patient_ID) AS P ON  vwGenPatInfo.Patient_ID=P.Patient_ID
    WHERE  
        vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Status='N'
    ORDER BY 
        vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_Sched_Department_ID,  
        vwGenPatApptInfo.Appt_DateTime
```

the data currently is like this: the last number is the count of previous noshows. So we want to break this down like Adult Medicine_NS 3, Dental_NS 9. the datetime showing is the noshow from previous day. The call room will call them to re-schedule.

```
Patient_Name Appt_Sched_Departmen Appt_NoShow_Date Previous No Show Count
8/31/2016 No Shows 8/30/2016
Patient_number
Sinca Blay  Adult Medicine 8/30/2016 12:05:46PM 12
Wiske Semns Adult Medicine 8/30/2016 5:25:32PM 4
Rose  Alhar Adult Medicine 8/30/2016 5:57:01PM 6
```

Comment: You would need to start with a query that is actually valid. This query you posted is obviously now what you are using as it isn't even close to valid. You have every column aliased a "j" which will work but it pretty much useless. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Look into [`GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx)  it allows you to aggregate at multiple levels in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [analytic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx), [aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) and [ranking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) window functions for this.

Here is an untested query to give you an idea:

```
SELECT      Patient_ID,
            Patient_Name, 
            Appt_Sched_Department_ID,
            Appt_Sched_Department_Descr,
            Appt_NoShow_Date_Today,
            Appt_NoShow_Date_Prev,
            NotShowCount
FROM       (SELECT      app.Patient_ID,
                        pat.Patient_Name,
                        app.Appt_Sched_Department_ID,
                        app.Appt_Sched_Department_Descr,
                        app.Appt_DateTime AS Appt_NoShow_Date_Today,
                        LEAD(app.Appt_DateTime) 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY app.Patient_ID 
                                  ORDER BY app.Appt_DateTime DESC) AS Appt_NoShow_Date_Prev,
                        COUNT(app.Appt_Status) 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY app.Patient_ID) AS NotShowCount,
                        ROW_NUMBER() 
                            OVER (PARTITION BY app.Patient_ID 
                                  ORDER BY app.Appt_DateTime DESC) AS rn
            FROM        vwGenPatApptInfo app
            INNER JOIN  vwGenPatInfo pat
                     ON pat.Patient_ID = app.Patient_ID
            WHERE       app.Appt_Status = 'N'
           ) AS base
WHERE       rn = 1
AND         Appt_NoShow_Date_Today >= DATEADD(day,  DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
ORDER BY    Appt_Sched_Department_ID,
            Appt_NoShow_Date_Today
```

The inner query gets all records with status 'N', but adds information:

- `Appt_NoShow_Date_Prev`: the `Appt_DateTime` value of the next record if the records are sorted by descending `Appt_DateTime` (for the same patient: this is the "window").
- `NotShowCount`: The number of records in that window.
- `rn`: the sequential record number in that window, again when records are sorted by descending `Appt_DateTime`.

The outer query only keeps the records with `rn = 1`, which means: the record with the most recent `Appt_DateTime` per patient. As a second condition, this `Appt_DateTime` must be today (after last midnight): this makes sure we only list patients which were absent today.